# Flutter failed to install the following sdk components

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, sdk

I was getting error like this when I was trying to do `flutter run` in project that was just created using `flutter create <project-name>`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

I've fixed it by changing `compileSdkVersion flutter.complieSdkVersion` to `compileSdkVersion 33`.

But now I am getting an error when trying to do `flutter run` with shared preferences package.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugAidl'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

The problem is I have installed android sdk version 33.0.0, 31.0.0 and all 30 versions available in Android Studio so idk what should I also install...
And also when I do `flutter doctor --android-licences` and accept it, flutter says that some licenses still not accepted.
I am using Pop!_OS 20.04.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this you just need migrate to Ubuntu or Windows. That will definitely solve the problem

Comment: Why would switching to Ubuntu or Windows solve this problem?

Comment: idk actually, like on some linux versions flutter might be broken or something...